# How can i access CrateDB Admin UI on Ubuntu server 18.04 across the LAN?

Tags: cratedb

I installed CrateDB on an Ubuntu server 18.04 across the LAN. But I am not able to access the Admin-UI and I get the following message:

`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.102:4200.`

How can i solve this problem?

CrateDB is running on the server and this is the status:

```
sudo systemctl status crate.service

crate.service - CrateDB Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/crate.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-06-30 14:15:38 +04; 18min ago
Docs: https://crate.io/docs/
Main PID: 17614 (java)
Tasks: 35 (limit: 4649)
CGroup: /system.slice/crate.service
└─17614 java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+U
...
```

Comment: What does your 'network.*' configuration look like?

Comment: Do you mean network configuration for CrateDB?. Where can i find it?. Otherwise, i have no problem with firewall and accessing all other services like apache, MySQL etc over the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

per default cratedb binds itself to local which means that you can't access it from the outside.

you need to set `network.host` to something like `_site_`.

https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/config/node.html#hosts

you need to make sure all the bootstrap checks pass: https://crate.io/docs/crate/guide/en/latest/admin/bootstrap-checks.html

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

And in addition to what @Johannes Moser has replied, that first you need to add your machine's IP in *crate.yml* file, against *network.host*.

Then optionally you can specify *psql.port*, which defaults to 5432, and then you can access Crate from outside like:

**l.oc.al.ip/PSQL_PORT**

## Solution 2

Use [nGROK](https://ngrok.com/download)

> ngrok exposes local servers behind NATs and firewalls to the public
> internet over secure tunnels.